# Where to place CMake macro definitions?

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, poco-libraries

I'm writing an application that relies on the [Poco](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco) project. I just need a few sub modules but they use macros defined by the Poco project which are stored in a cmake folder at the root of the Poco folder structure.

I don't want to drag the whole Poco folder as I don't want to link my project to the whole Poco framework. How can I make those macros available to my project?

Comment: Any feedback for the answers?

Comment: Haven't been able to work on this as the day job keeps me very busy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure to well understand what you need. But why not simply include de file containing the macros by this way with cmake ?

```
include(path/to/Poco/cmake/macros.cmake)
```

Answer (score -2):

- Take the Poco project
- Open the main CMakeLists.txt of Poco and comment (with `#`) all the `add_subdirectory` commands for the directories you don't need.
- Try to build Poco
- If it fails, add back the directories which contains the missing dependencies (in short, you might think you don't need a directory, but it might be that one of the directories you need depends on another directory)
- When it builds, you can delete all the directories for which you have removed the command `add_subdirectory`

Comment: Bad answer because it's intrusive in the Poco project, and then you have to duplicate it to avoid conflicts with other application using Poco. Moreover, you have no assurance your modifications works with another system configuration (it's the goal of CMake...) after removing parts.